# Virtuoso 42000 Error SR186: How to grant permission on dbpedia with a SPARQL Query?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

On [de.dbpedia](http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql), I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
{
    ?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein.
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
Optional {?name <http://de.dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?deathDate}
MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
}
union{
    SERVICE silent <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
    ?name dcterms:subject category-en:Princely_Family_of_Liechtenstein.
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
Optional {?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?deathDate}
MINUS {?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?d}
}
}
}
```

Getting the following error:

> Virtuoso 42000 Error SR186: No permission to execute procedure DB.DBA.SPARUL_LOAD_SERVICE_DATA with user ID 106, group ID 106

Is there a way to grant permission? How can I get my results? btw:  the "Optional" is only to check if I get the correct results...

Thanks a lot in advance

Fobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has multiple issues. First, you need to replace both your `<http://de.dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate>` with `dbpedia-owl:deathDate`. Second, I am assuming you are trying to get all the `?deathDate`s and then filter the ones that have no `?deathDate`. If so, this is the query you need to write without getting into trouble with permissions:

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
{
?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein.
?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
Optional {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
union{
SERVICE silent <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
?name dcterms:subject category-en:Princely_Family_of_Liechtenstein.
?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
Optional {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
}
filter (!bound(?deathDate))
}
```